# Customer email is required

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I've looked through many forums and can not find a solution to the error I am getting.

When a user checks out and selects register while checking out they get to the end of the process and a error pops up saying "customer email is required".

Here is the Exception:

```
2012-08-23T14:35:06+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Customer_Exception' with message 'Customer email is required' in /home/psc/public_html/app/Mage.php:579
Stack trace:
#0 /home/psc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php(76): Mage::exception('Mage_Customer', 'Customer email ...')
#1 /home/psc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1122): Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer->_beforeSave(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
#2 /home/psc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
#3 /home/psc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(151): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#4 /home/psc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#5 /home/psc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#6 /home/psc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(774): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#7 /home/psc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(511): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#8 /home/psc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#9 /home/psc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#10 /home/psc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /home/psc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /home/psc/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /home/psc/public_html/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

Comment: /home/psc/public_html/app/Mage.php:579 is the function that throws the Exception. The problem is what I have explained above. Thank you for your useless answer.

Comment: the error simply says `Customer Email` is required. When a user wants to register in Magento, email is the required field without it they can't place order.

Comment: Right, this is all that Magento is giving me. On the OnePAge checkout the email is filled in.

Comment: Not sure why this is voted down? If you know where I would get more info on the error to share please let me know. As far as I know this is all I'm being given on the error.

Comment: Has your template been edited? Maybe you have changed the name of the input containing the email address or broke the html? Although that shouldn't throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the shipping extension that was installed need to be updated. Once updated Everything worked as normal.

Thanks,

- DAne